# form_for first argument nil error in Rails with defined associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a simple Blog application using Rails and I'm trying to create the ability to submit a comment for a post. However, I keep getting this error

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

```
<h3> Submit a Comment </h3>

<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |c| %> 
//Error is here, @comment appears to be nil and I'm not sure why 
//(I've checked both cases)

  <%= c.label :body, "Comment: " %>
  <br />
  <%= c.text_area :body %>
```

I've checked the other posts that had a similar issue but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find params[:post_id]

    comment_params = params.require(:comment).permit(:body)

    @comment = Comment.new comment_params
    @comment.post = @post
    # Why is my comment nil?

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: "Comment successful"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Comment unsuccessful. Please do not enter an empty comment"
      render "/posts/show"
    end

  end

  def destroy
    # To be implemented
  end

end
```

EDIT: Solved, forgot to add @comment = Comment.new in the show method in my Post controller

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What does you controller look like?

Comment: added my comments controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new comment. You should either:

A. Have `@comment = Comment.new` somewhere in your controller

OR

B. Instantiate it right then and there with

```
form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |c| #...
```

Comment: hmm, I have that in my controller - unless I have a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: Specifically, it should be in the `show` method of your posts controller (assuming that is where the add a comment option is offered)

Comment: Ah that was exactly it! Thank you!

Comment: @BruceWayne Please remember to accept the answer (click the checkmark) if I've answered your question.